# REST _api/social.following/stopfollowing not working - internal error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I'm inside a **SharePoint 2013 App Part**.

I want to stop following a site.

My code looks like this:

```
var unfollowSiteUrl = appweburl + "/_api/social.following/stopfollowing";
var unfollowUrl = "http://portal.devlab003/sites/Kace";

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: unfollowSiteUrl,
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "actor": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
                },
                "ActorType": 2,
                "ContentUri": unfollowUrl,
                "Id": null
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            // doesn't matter if it is present or not
            //"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('The user has stopped following the document.');
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            // Errror
            debugger;
        }
    }
);
```

The error i get is:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":"6, Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException",
        "message":{
            "lang":"en-US",
            "value":"The operation failed because an internal error occurred. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException. Internal error code: 11."
        },
        "innererror":{
            "message":"The operation failed because an internal error occurred. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentException. Internal error code: 11.",
            "type":"Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException",
            "stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.TryTranslateExceptionAndThrow(Exception exception)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialUtil.InvokeWithExceptionTranslation[T](ISocialOperationManager target, String name, Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialRestFollowingManager.StopFollowing(SPSocialActorInfo actor)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialRestFollowingManagerServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethod(Boolean mainRequestPath, Object value, ServerStub serverProxy, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation methodInfo, Boolean isExtensionMethod, Boolean isIndexerMethod)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathMember(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, Object value, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)"
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't make a difference if i do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: unfollowSiteUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "actor": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
            },
            "ActorType": 2,
            "ContentUri": unfollowUrl,
            "Id": null
        }
    }),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('The user has stopped following the document.');
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        // Errror
        debugger;
    }
});
```

I have googled a lot but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

**Edit**

If i change the url from

```
var unfollowSiteUrl = appweburl + "/_api/social.following/stopfollowing";
```

to

```
var unfollowSiteUrl = appweburl + "/_api/social.following/isfollowed";
```

it works.

Answer (score 1):

The App needs to have the specific right. In this case the **Tenant** needed **Write** Permission.

BTW it does not help to grant a higher right for **User Profiles (Social)** than **Read**.

[image: App Properties]